# Is there any option for Magento to mobile app?

Tags: mobile, magento-1.9.3.2

Am new to magento and I have developed one magento website. If I want to make the site for mobile application,how can I do that? Is there any way or option or plugins availble or else I need to do new app separately. Anyone can give me solution or any link is available to proceed for app?

Answer (score 0):

Credits  : [AndroidGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155805/androidgeek) for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682462/how-to-create-your-own-magento-mobile-application-for-android-and-iphone)

There are few Steps for that::

1. Magento offers two API's to develop your app in Android
                a. **SOAP API**
                b. **XML-RPC**
2. If you want to use `XMLRPC API`,then you have to download **it's library** and use it in your Project.
3. You have to create a New User in your `Magento Store` with **roles**.That you can do by **loging** in to your **Admin module** and the option is under the `system->WebServices->User && Roles`...You have to create first roles and then create a user and assign the roles to the User.
4. You have to use the `UserName` and `APIKey` that you give in the `Magento` Store for calling the **login Function.**
5. Calling the Login function,you will Receive a **Session Id**,that you have to **store** and **Use** it in your **further calls**.

Some of the helpful links to **get Started** Are::

6. [Link-1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api)
7. [Link-2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/255191/)
8. [Link-3](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/consuming-the-magento-xmlrpc-web-service-through-android/)
9. [Link-4](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/android-magento-mobile-boilerplate/)

10.[link-5](http://inchoo.net/magento/develop-your-own-magento-mobile-application/)

11. [My Questions And their Solutions On SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155805/haresh-chaudhary?tab=questions)

**plugins** [Not tested] :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/build-mobile-app-for-magento-store-mobicommerce.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mofluid-magento-mobile-app-builder.html

Below are some more links that will help  :

[apk file required for creating mobile app for magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62620/apk-file-required-for-creating-mobile-app-for-magento)

[Magento Mobile App - How to create it?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122624/magento-mobile-app-how-to-create-it)

[is it possible to create mobile app using the rest api / or soap?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26124/is-it-possible-to-create-mobile-app-using-the-rest-api-or-soap)

[Best option for Magento Mobile APP API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70206/best-option-for-magento-mobile-app-api)

Answer (score 0):

If your eyes are on to create a mobile app for your website then I would advise you to go with Magento Mobile App Builder. This plugin is a ready-made framework which converts an online website into an app without involving you in any sort of coding or programming.

For more info:

[Magento](https://www.knowband.com/magento-mobile-app-builder)

[Magento 2](https://www.knowband.com/magento-2-mobile-app-builder)

I hope this helps you to create a better mobile app for your website.